# knockout js get data on check box selecting individual

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using knockoutjs for binding, I am binding data in a list with a checkbox, I have a button which is used to select all the checkboxes when I click, but now I want to create new function on individual click, or check when it is selected I need to get all data related to that checkbox here is my code:

```
add code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/102/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/103/

Comment: @thanks,actually i solved it in different way

Comment: Can you share your solution as an answer which shall help others who might run into this?

Comment: @thanks for your replay,i solved it